# Sansevieria laurentii snake plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, leaves, snake-plants

My plant is not growing straight up. It seems to spreading. I know these type of plants grown straight up and tall. What could be the cause of this? I water once a week. Its near a bright window. I use soil and perlite.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is just filling up the space with babies. Once that is done, it will start going up. Use a diluted liquid houseplant fertilizer monthly. Looks great!